# EJB won't get injected in my RestEASY resource class

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-3.0, resteasy, wildfly-8

my configuration is: JBoss Wildfly 8.0.0, EJB 3.0, Resteasy 3.0.6, EAR project with web, ejb, api modules.

I have a rest resource annotated with @Path in my web module:

```
@Path("/boxes")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Stateless
public class BoxServiceResource {

@EJB
private IBoxService boxService;

@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String test() {
    return "test string";
}

@GET
@Path("/list/{date}/{type}")
public List<BoxDTO> getBoxesForDate(@PathParam("date") String date,
                                    @PathParam("type") DateType type) {

    return boxService.getBoxesForDate(new Date(), DateType.DAY);

}

@GET
@Path("/byId/{id}")
public BoxDTO getBoxById(@PathParam("id") Long id) {

    return boxService.getBoxById(5L);

}
}
```

This is the bean:

```
@Stateless
public class BoxServiceImpl implements IBoxService {

@Override
public List<BoxDTO> getBoxesForDate(Date date,
                                    DateType type) {

    List<BoxDTO> boxes = new ArrayList<>(4);
    return boxes;
}

@Override
public BoxDTO getBoxById(Long id) {

    BoxDTO box = new BoxDTO();
    return box;

}

}
```

Additionally I have the Application extending class which has no overriden implementation:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class BoxesRestApplication extends Application {

}
```

My web.xml contains only a JSF servlet, and nothing besides that. I have the beans.xml files in each module. However, the EJB won't get injected. I have also tried with @Inject with the same result. The REST resource itself gets published and I can call the test method, but when calling the other two methods it fails with NullPointerException. I have already read tons of tutorials and solutions, however, none worked for me. Thank you your help.

Comment: How is the IBoxService annotated? The IBoxService and BoxServiceImpl is defined in different EJB Module like BoxServiceResource or all are in the same module (IBoxService, BoxServiceImpl and BoxServiceResource)?

Comment: Can you post StackTrace too?

Comment: There are three modules: web, ejb, api. The API contains the Interface(no annotations here, simple Java Interface). Api is packaged as JAR. Tje Ejb module contains the interface implementation (i.e. Stateless bean) - is packaged es EJB. Web is where the resource class resides. I should mention that I also have a JSF bean in WEB module too, where it gets injected without problems.

Comment: I would suggest to annotate the interface with @ Local annotation, if it does not work try annotating the BoxServiceImpl with @ Local, butin my opinion annotating the interface IBoxService with local shoud work. Of course perfrom clean&build and redeploy to be sure ;)

Comment: I had similar project, the difference was that I had interface and bean in one EJB module. If I forgot to annotate the interface like @ Local I got null pointer, because the bean wasnt wired (because container did not know which one) to the target.

Answer (score 1):

Try annotating the IBoxService with @Local annotation. For more information about this annotation see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Local.html). The interface should then look:

```
@Local
public interface IBoxService{
    public List<BoxDTO> getBoxesForDate(Date date, DateType type);
    public BoxDTO getBoxById(Long id);

    // other methods you would need
}
```